# #1054 unknown column in on clause error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT Ychastok_number AS 'Номер участка',podrazdelenie.Name AS Объект,type.Name AS Машина,avto.Marka AS Марка, avto.Gos_number AS 'Гос.Номер', avto.Invent_num AS 'Инвентарный номер', SUM(OtrabotanoMachine_hours) as 'Часов в рабочих сменах',SUM(sec.Hours) as Простои,SUM(TimeRaboty_dvigatelya)AS 'Отработано времени',TRUNCATE((SUM(sec.Hours)/ SUM(OtrabotanoMachine_hours))*100,1) as 'Процент простоев от часов рабочих смен', TRUNCATE((SUM(TimeRaboty_dvigatelya)/ SUM(OtrabotanoMachine_hours))*100,1) as 'Процент работ', CONVERT(group_concat(concat(prostoy.Prichina,'=',sec.Hours) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'Причины простоев'
FROM
jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain main
INNER JOIN avto ON main.Marka=avto.ID_Avto
INNER JOIN typeconstructionmechanizm type ON main.Machine = type.ID_TypeConstructionMechanizm
INNER JOIN podrazdelenie ON main.Ychastok = podrazdelenie.ID_Podrazdelenie
INNER JOIN prostoy ON jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond.Prostoy = prostoy.ID_Prosyoy
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id_fk, SUM(Hours) AS Hours
   FROM jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond 
   GROUP BY id_fk) sec ON sec.id_fk = main.id
GROUP BY  Ychastok_number,podrazdelenie.Name,type.Name,avto.Marka,avto.Gos_number,avto.Invent_num
```

And I'm getting this error:

**#1054 - Unknown column 'jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond.Prostoy' in 'on clause'**

after adding this row

```
INNER JOIN prostoy ON jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond.Prostoy = prostoy.ID_Prosyoy
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: Look at your schema, the error is obvious, that field does not exists, or you spelt it incorrectly

Comment: I would rather say, the table is not known, since I do not see the table in the from clause. It is in a subquery, but the subquery has a proper alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no table with the alias or name `jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond`.  Hence the column is unknown.

In fact, there is no evidence of this table at all in the query, except in the subquery.  You can:

- use an (appropriate) column from another table
- include the table you want in the `FROM` clause
- put the `join` in the subquery

It is unclear what you want to accomplish; so it is hard to make a concrete suggestion.

Comment: It's in the subquery.

Comment: @Shadow . . . I saw that and revised the answer.