# Unknown Column Error in on CLAUSE using alias MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have this set of SQL command

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        REPEAT('    ', (COUNT(parent.itemName) - 1)),
        node.itemName
        ) AS 'NAME_',
    node.itemNo AS 'ITEM_CODE',
    node.assemblyNo AS 'ASSEMBLY_NO.',
    ref_item_type.itemTypeName AS 'TYPE_',
    node.description AS 'DESCRIPTION_',
    node.serialNo AS 'SERIAL_NO',
    node.hardwareNo AS 'HARDWARE_NO',
    node.modelNo AS 'MODEL_NO',
    node.version AS 'VERSION_',
    ref_item_uom.uomName AS 'UNIT_',
    ref_item_cat.catName AS 'CATEGORY_',
    ref_item_product_type.prodTypeName AS 'PRODUCT TYPE',
    man_network.networkName AS 'NETWORK_',
    ref_item_package.packageName AS 'PACKAGE_',
    node.reorderPoint AS 'REORDER_POINT',
    node.cost AS 'COST_',
    node.price AS 'PRICE_',
    node.surcharge AS 'SURECHARGE_',
    node.validity AS 'VALIDITY_',
    node.validityUnit AS 'VALIDITY_UNIT',
    node.isSpecialItem AS 'SPECIAL_',
    node.isActive AS 'IS_ACTIVE_',
    node.itemIndex AS 'ITEM_INDEX'
FROM man_item AS node,
    man_item AS parent
LEFT JOIN ref_item_type ON ref_item_type.itemTypeNo = node.itemType
LEFT JOIN ref_item_uom ON ref_item_uom.uomNo = node.uomNo
LEFT JOIN ref_item_cat ON ref_item_cat.catNo = node.itemCat
LEFT JOIN ref_item_product_type ON ref_item_product_type.prodTypeNo = node.prodTypeNo
LEFT JOIN man_network ON man_network.networkNo = node.networkNo
LEFT JOIN ref_item_package ON ref_item_package.packageNo = node.packageNo
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft
        AND parent.rgt
    AND node.isVisible = 'Y'
```

And I got some error

> 1054 - Unknown column 'node.itemType' in 'on clause'

Did I miss something?

PS: I forgot to mention my fields in my table
here it is btw

```
itemIndex   
itemNo
subItem 
assemblyNo
refNo  
prodTypeNo 
networkNo
packageNo
itemName
itemType
itemSubTypeNo
itemCat
uomNo
serialNo
hardwareNo
modelNo
version
cost
price
surcharge
validity
validityUnit
logoLocation
fileHash
lft
rgt
isSpecialItem
isActive
```

My bad for not posting the table structure earlier, makes more confusing and being vague

Comment: Read the error message again. The `node` table (which is `man_item` table) has no `itemType` column.

Comment: firstly, explicitly define the `inner join` and not using a `comma`

Comment: maybe the correct field is `node.itemNo`

Comment: updated post, my bad for not posting my fields

Comment: @maSTAShuFu inner join is much slower than using comma in MySQL.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields...

Comment: @muffi at least you have something new learned today.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: yes, I learned how to speed down queries :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing this part of the code to a proper join:

`FROM man_item AS node,
    man_item AS parent
LEFT JOIN ref_item_type ON ref_item_type.itemTypeNo = node.itemType`

The engine might not know how to read the "," separated table list and then a left join and throwing a random error instead.

`FROM man_item AS node
 LEFT OUTER JOIN man_item AS parent
  ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
  AND node.isVisible = 'Y'
 LEFT JOIN ref_item_type 
  ON ref_item_type.itemTypeNo = node.itemType`

Comment: Happy to help. Could you select it as the answer so it does not remain an open question.

Answer (score 0):

below  from clause looks odd

```
 FROM man_item AS node, man_item AS parent
```

below link has solution for similar problem
[#1054 unknown column in on clause error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239719/1054-unknown-column-in-on-clause-error)

Comment: I have modified the sql provided in this [link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) using this sql syntax "SELECT CONCAT( REPEAT( ' ', (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) ), node.name) AS name
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;"

Comment: Yes based on my table structure. If there are no joins the query works fine however if I use the following joins (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER and OUTER) that error occurs

Comment: as per @maSTAShuFu suggestion, chane it to man_item AS node inner join man_item AS paren